# I have white line when I hover over menu item in my navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am working on a website and I have a problem because when I hover over a menu item, drop down menu item in my navigation as drop down appears white line across my 2 menu items appears on a menu item and next one. I really don't know what is happening. Here is my code for navigation ( I am using Genesis framework for Wordpress)

```css
.genesis-nav-menu a {
 border: none;
 color: #919594;
 display: block;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: 35px;
}

.genesis-nav-menu a:hover,
.genesis-nav-menu .current-menu-item > a,
.genesis-nav-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a:hover {
 color: #C77D3C;
 border: 2px solid #C77D3C;
 border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.site-header .sub-menu` has a `border-top`. If you remove that one, it is also removed from the page.

I can see you have commented it out in your CSS-file, but it's clearly being applied. Why it is applied is a mystery you'll have to solve yourself. At least now you know where it comes from :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much my friend that solved my problems :D Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

stroke 1155 on your css file

```
.site-header .sub-menu {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```